# bind input type value to angular expression

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

how to bind an value attribute of input to angular expression

```
 <tr>
<td><label> Cash To Collect</label></td>
<td><input type="text" ng-model="Receipt.codToCollect" required
 placeholder="Amount To Collect" class="form-control"> <span
 class="help-block"></span></td></tr>
<tr>
 <td><label> Cash Handed Over</label></td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model="Receipt.codPaid" required
   placeholder=" Cash Paid" class="form-control"> <span
                                class="help-block"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label> Shortfall Amount</label></td>
<td><input type="text" ng-model="Receipt.shortFallAmount"
ng-value="{{Receipt.codToCollect-Receipt.codPaid}}" required
placeholder=" ShortFall Amount" class="form-control"> <span
class="help-block"></span></td>
</tr>
```

the value for shortfall should get calculated according to the expression????

Comment: `ngValue` is for `<option>` and `[radio]` inputs only.  If I'm following the logic of what this form is supposed to do, I'm not even sure why `Receipt.shortFallAmount` would even be bound to an input box in the first place; I don't think you want the users to have the ability to change it...

Answer (score 0):

**First way**
You don't need to set the value at all. ng-model takes care of it all:

-->set the input value from the model
-->update the model value when you change the input
-->update the input value when you change the model from js

**Second way**
If you don't wan't to use ng-model there is ng-value you can try.